# replace text between strings in php

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace, between

I need to find all instances of a two strings and replace all the text enclosed between them.  E.g.:

```
[LINK]mySite.com[NAME]Click to visit my site[ENDLINK]
```

Needs to be replaced with:

```
<a href="mySite.com">Click to visit my site</a>
```

So far I have the following which is working:

```
    if(stristr("$text","[LINK]") && stristr("$text","[ENDLINK]")):
        $text = str_ireplace("[LINK]","\n<a href=\"" ,"$text");
        $text = str_ireplace("[NAME]", "\" target=\"_self\"><u>", "$text");
        $text = str_ireplace("[ENDLINK]","</u></a>","$text");
    endif;
```

However,  it replaces [NAME] in all the other custom tags I am using, for example I also have:

```
   if(stristr("$text","[FILE]") && stristr("$text","[ENDFILE]")):
        $text = str_ireplace("[FILE]","\n<a href=\"" ,"$text");
        $text = str_ireplace("[NAME]", "\" target=\"_blank\"><u>", "$text");
        $text = str_ireplace("[ENDFILE]","</u></a>","$text");
    endif;
```

As you can see [FILE] uses target="_blank" and [LINK] uses target="_self",  when I use the above script it replaces all instances of [NAME] to "_blank".

Renaming the tag [NAME] isn't a viable option as there are 1000's of entries already using it in the database and the users are accustomed to using it as is.

Is there a simple method to get this working?

Comment: Is your `$text` contains both `[LINK]mySite.com[NAME]Click to visit my site[ENDLINK]` and `[FILE]mySite.com[NAME]Click to download my file[ENDFILE]` at once?

Comment: Yes,  and multiple times for each in $text.

Comment: In this case all `IF` statements is always `true`, because in the `$text` there are [LINK], [ENDLINK], [FILE], [ENDFILE]. First `str_ireplace("[NAME]"..` replace all [NAME].. You need to split `$text` to the parts, contains only one link or file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "[LINK]picture-large.jpg[NAME][IMAGE]picture-small.jpg[ENDIMAGE][ENDLINK] ... [LINK]mySite.com[NAME]Click to visit my site[endlink] lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ... [LINK]anothersite.com[name]Don't click here[ENDLINK] and here goes the file: [FILE]file.pdf[NAME]This is link to file[ENDFILE]";

function replaceFiles($match) {
    return '<a href="'.$match[1].'" target="_blank"><u>'.$match[2].'</u></a>';
}

function replaceImages($match) {
    return '<img src="'.$match[1].'" />';
}

function replaceLinks($match) {
    return '<a href="'.$match[1].'" target="_self"><u>'.$match[2].'</u></a>';
}


$text = preg_replace_callback('/\[FILE\](.*?)\[NAME\](.*?)\[ENDFILE\]/i', 'replaceFiles', $text);
$text = preg_replace_callback('/\[IMAGE\](.*?)\[ENDIMAGE\]/i', 'replaceImages', $text);
$text = preg_replace_callback('/\[LINK\](.*?)\[NAME\](.*?)\[ENDLINK\]/i', 'replaceLinks', $text);
```

Comment: It works,  however is there a way to make it case-insensitive?  E.g. [NAME] and [name] both being equal?
And,  many time different tags are embedded within one another,  with this method the inner tag doesn't get rendered?

Comment: Use "i" modifier at the end of the regular pattern for case-insensitive search .... '/\[LINK\](.*?)\[NAME\](.*?)\[ENDLINK\]/i'

Comment: Any ideas on how to process tags that are embedded?  Users often use something like:  [LINK]picture-large.jpg[NAME][IMAGE]picture-small.jpg[ENDIMAGE][ENDLINK].   With the example you provided the [IMAGE] portion doesn't get processed.

Comment: Discovered the issue I was having...my [IMAGE] tags include an [ALT] tag in them for which the users were not using. By populating the ALT tag the preg_replace now works. E.g. [LINK]picture-large.jpg[NAME][IMAGE]picture-small.jpg[ALT]A small picture[ENDIMAGE][ENDLINK]. Is there a simple way to have IMAGE still be parsed regardless of ALT being used or not?

Answer (score 0):

This will only return if the entire pattern is matched:

```
public function replaceLinks($text){
    return preg_replace('/\[LINK](.*?)\[NAME](.*?)\[ENDLINK]/', "<a href='$1'>$2</a>", $text);
}
```

First of all it is working by using a pattern which matches the whole thing, not just parts of the link.

Here is a walkthrough of the regular expression (not a literal step by step of how a regular expression engine works before you regex nerds complain):

1. Forward slashes are used to contain the expression.
2. We put `\` before the `[` to escape it, otherwise it is interpreted as the start of a character class.
3. We match the literal `LINK]`.
4. We create a capturing group for any character `.`, any number of times `*`, but with a lazy modifier `?`. This is back referenced by the `$1` in the replacement string.
5. I won't explain the rest because it is the same process for the rest of the string.

Here is a PHPUnit class which demonstrates the correct behaviour:

```
class Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

  public function replaceLinks($text){
    return preg_replace('/\[LINK](.*?)\[NAME](.*?)\[ENDLINK]/', "<a href='$1'>$2</a>", $text);
  }

  public function testCase1(){

    // Must replace links
    $input = "[LINK]mySite.com[NAME]Click to visit my site[ENDLINK]";
    $output = $this->replaceLinks($input);
    $expected = "<a href='mySite.com'>Click to visit my site</a>";
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $output);

  }

  public function testCase2(){

    // Must not replace files 
    $input = "[FILE]mySite.com[NAME]Click to visit my site[ENDFILE]";
    $output = $this->replaceLinks($input);
    $expected = "[FILE]mySite.com[NAME]Click to visit my site[ENDFILE]";
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $output);
  }

}
```

Comment: I think this works,  however I'm not very familiar with php class/objects.   And I suspect I'd have to change how the current function for interpreting these tags is written in thousands of lines of code.

Comment: Don't worry about the class, just use the function. I have provided it so you can see test cases I have run. It is just another way of developing, by writing tests first and then writing your code, so when the tests pass you know your code is solid.

Comment: Ok,  got it working just using the function.  Though I had to re-order and mix in my original method for my IMAGE tags that users embed within the LINK tag in order for it to parse those correctly. E.g.  Users often use something like: [LINK]picture-large.jpg[NAME][IMAGE]picture-small.jpg[ENDIMAGE][ENDLINK]. With the example you provided the [IMAGE] portion didn't get parsed.  Any suggestions on how I could implement your method to accomplish this cleanly?

Comment: Do you mean how to write an alternative function for IMAGE tags, or what approach to take? The approach would probably to convert the inner-most tags first.

Comment: Tried a few alterations but it didn't seem to work.   Curious as to why it doesn't convert the embedded tags?

Comment: Discovered the issue I was having...my [IMAGE] tags include an [ALT] tag in them for which the users were not using.  By populating the ALT tag the preg_replace now works.   E.g.   [LINK]picture-large.jpg[NAME][IMAGE]picture-small.jpg[ALT]A small picture[ENDIMAGE][ENDLINK].
Is there a simple way to have IMAGE still be parsed regardless of ALT being used or not?

Comment: You'll just have to get used to writing regular expressions because the complications will never end. The joy of programming :)

Comment: Thanks for you help Henry.   I'm not quite sure on the cleanest way to accomplish this though.